# Priority queue from 2 sources in AnyLogic

Tags: priority-queue, anylogic

Good day! I tried to build the network model in AnyLogic  8.7.6. I have 2 sources with different priorities (the packets from the first source obtain priority 2, and the packets from the second source obtain priority 1). The packets from the sources are transmitted to the Queue. The Queue should sort them by Priority.

[image]

The priority parameters are defined in Agents at the Sources.

[image]

I made a simple experiment. The Source 1  generates 1 agent per sec and the Source 2 generates 10 agents per sec. We see that the queue is empty :(

[image]

I have no idea why. The Queue doesn't sort them according to their priority.

P.S. Sorry, I have russian language version of Anylogic.

Comment: How can we know if the sorting is not working if there is nothing in the queue? Please delete all the connections out of the queue so that there is a queue that builds up...if you have two queues connected to each other agents will enter the first one and immediately go to the next queue... so they are never prioritized because they never queue in the first queue, where I assume you set up the prioritization.

Comment: Thank you! I understand what was my problem. The queue can't sort anything since it doesn't collect anything. The agents leave the queue immediately. So simple....
However, the number of my agents starts with 39. Not 1....

Comment: (That was my very first statement in my original answer ;-) ) You can ignore the agent number, or you can create your own function and choose what you want to display. Check my final picture in my updated question. 
(If my answer helped you solve your problem remember to accept it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the queue capacities, if you have two queues connected to each other agents will enter the first one and immediately go to the next queue... so they are never prioritized because they never queue in the first queue, where I assume you set up the prioritization.

Try deleting the connection between the two queues and simply see if the agents get ordered according to your priority.

See a small test below

I have a custom agent type with a variable `priority` and a simple flow chart with 2 sources and a queue

[image]

As per your example, I am setting the priority variable of the agents generated in Source1 to 2, and in source 2 they are set to 1.

In the queue, I set my ordering to be based on priority and tell the block to use the priority variable inside the agents (the higher the higher the priority)

[image]

For the example, I set source1 to generate agents every minute and source 2 to generate every second.

The expectation is that as soon as an agent from source1 gets generated it will jump the queue and go stand first inline

When I run the model and I click to see the details of the queue, I can see that as soon as the agent from source1 gets created it jumps the line.

[image]

You can always create a custom toString() function to determine what must be displayed when you click on the queue block

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, it doesn't work.  I just leave two sources, connect them with the queue and then connect the queue with the sink. Sources generate agents with the parameter "Priority". The sorting of the queue is made by this parameter. The capacity of the queue is unlimited.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I updated my answer with a very simple example. I hope this helps you get a workable solution to your problem. If this still does not help please provide the prioritization details of your blocks, similar to what I have done

Comment: And what is more interesting thing is that the queue can sort packets within agents that were generated at the same time. So, if I change the two sources by One source. And this Source generates agents by uniform_discr(1,5) the queue sorts the packets within one Creation timestamp.

Comment: The queue will sort the agents every time a new agent arrives in the queue. 
Not sure if your issue is now resolved or not?

Comment: I have updated the task. No, it still doesn't work :(